# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios' when trying to test Airflow DAG task

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, airflow

I created a DAG to try SQLite connectivity in Airflow.

When I ran the command:

```
airflow tasks test user_processing creating_table 2022-01-01
```

to test my task

I got the error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
from termios import *
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'

I have read at a lot of places that termios is not available on Windows but is that really all? Can I not try something else to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, my bad. I was trying to use it via the simple shell, I needed to get into the Airflow CLI in order to use this command.

that command is:

```
docker exec -it <dag_id> /bin/bash
```